# how to find which row a value should be placed in a sorted dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to find which row a value should placed in a sorted dataframe.

For example,

```
value = [3, 2.5]

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3], 'y':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]})
```

since value has `x = 3` and `y = 2.5`, right place for this value will be between 8th and 9th.

I want to return 8 (lower index) in this case.

I tried to think a solution for it, but I really need help with this.

Comment: For us to help you, provide a minimal reproducible problem set containing sample input, expected output, actual output, and all relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. What you have provided falls short of this goal. See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way using [`bisect_left()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left):

```py
from bisect import bisect_left
i = bisect_left(list(zip(df.x, df.y)), tuple(value))
print(df.index[i])
```

Output:

```
8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Series.searchsorted`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html), which applies also a bisection algorithm under the hood.

You can generalize it to a DataFrame with multiple columns using the following function:

```
value = [3, 2.5]
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3], 'y':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]})

def bisect_left(df, arr):
    row_idx = 0
    for col_idx, val in zip(range(len(df.columns)), arr):
        row_idx += df.iloc[row_idx:, col_idx].searchsorted(val)
    return row_idx
```

Output:

```
>>> bisect_left(df, value)
8
```